# Django - use of related_name '+'?

Tags: python, django

In Django1.5 documentation , there is a section about `related_name`. the last paragraph is "If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set `related_name` to '+' or end it with '+'.

For example, this will ensure that the User model won’t have a backwards relation to this model: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')`. when should i use the "+" with `related_name`?

Comment: When you don't want a backwards relation created.

Comment: if i have a backwards relation, i can access to related objects conveniently. why not use it? I means that is there another purpose for the "+".

Comment: That is the only purpose.

Answer (score 31):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), a tool to disallow backwards relation, their words:

> If you’d prefer Django not to create a backwards relation, set related_name to '+' or end it with '+'.

Above answers are correct, but I wanted to make the answer extra clear for others.

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps when creating a reverse relationship would cause a conflict.  Consider the case where you have an abstract model and two sub-classes of said model:

```
class MyAbstractModel(models.Model):

    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True

    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, related_name="+")

class MyThing(MyAbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class MyOtherThing(MyAbstractModel):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Without the use of `"+"`, you'd get a naming conflict and Django would refuse to start.  Given that you don't actually *need* it in this case, it makes sense to just skip it.